# Get percentage value of pie chart on page reload Highcharts API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using pie chart in Angularjs and data is displaying correctly. I needed the percentage of each value covering in the pie chart and I got it by:

```
            tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 0,
            valuePrefix: yAxisDataPrefix,
            valueSuffix: yAxisDataSuffix,
              pointFormatter: function () {
                  let arr = [];
                  for (var i = 0; i < this.series.points.length; i++) {
                       console.log(this.series.points[i].percentage);
                   }
                   console.log(arr)
               }
        },
```

Although it prints the value whenever I hover on the pie chart. I need the values when the page reloads so I could use them in a table of my HTML file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The answer was provided in the following topic: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=49310. In the future, please try to not duplicate your question on the multiple support channels. Regards!